# Least squares problem, using derivative to find the normal equation?

Tags: numerical-methods

for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R^{m\times n}}$ and for $x,\epsilon \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $\epsilon$ small we have that

$\|A(\hat{x}+\epsilon)-b\|_2^2=(A(\hat{x}+\epsilon)-b)^T(A(\hat{x}+\epsilon)-b)=\|A\hat{x}-b\|_2^2+2\epsilon^T(A^TA\hat{x}-A^Tb)+\epsilon^TA^TA\epsilon$

Now the book states that the $A^TA\hat{x} - A^Tb$ can be treated as a derivative of something, and so we can set it equal to 0 to get the normal equation? How is this possible, what is it the derivative of and why do we set it to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f(x)=\frac12\,\|Ax-b\|^2$ and by you computation, only formalized differently
$$
\frac{d}{dt} f(x+t·ϵ)|_{t=0}=(Ax-b)^TA·ϵ.
$$
or transpose of that for the Gradient. For the (in this case unique) minimum the derivative has to be zero in all directions $ϵ$, which means 
$$
0=A^T(Ax-b)=A^TA-A^Tx.
$$
For a numerical solution you would employ the QR decomposition of $A$, which reduces, provided $A$ has maximum rank, $Rx=Q^Tb$.

Comment: Where did you get $f(x)$ from and where did you get that derivative??

Comment: I'm sorry i don't follow how your solutions leads from mine, could you please explain

Comment: By expanding the norm as you did and then differentiating the resulting quadratic expression.

Comment: Using my expression so I don't get confused, what are you differentiating with respect to and why?

Comment: Note that I replaced, as usual in the definition of a directional derivative, your $ϵ$ with the scaled $tϵ$. And if $v^Tϵ=0$ for all vectors $ϵ$ (even all in some ball of small positive radius), then $v=0$.